# Finding number of r's in the vector (Both R and r) before the first u

Tags: r

```
rquote <- "R's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
chars <- strsplit(rquote, split = "")[[1]]
```

in the above code we need to find the number of r's(R and r) in rquote

Comment: The title of the post and its content do not match, please clarify. Are you counting only *before the first u*?

Answer (score 3):

You could use substrings.

```
## find position of first 'u'
u1 <- regexpr("u", rquote, fixed = TRUE)
## get count of all 'r' or 'R' before 'u1'
lengths(gregexpr("r", substr(rquote, 1, u1), ignore.case = TRUE))
# [1] 5
```

This follows what you ask for in the title of the post. If you want the count of all the "r", case insensitive, then simplify the above to

```
lengths(gregexpr("r", rquote, ignore.case = TRUE))
# [1] 6
```

Then there's always `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
## count before first 'u'
stri_count_regex(stri_sub(rquote, 1, stri_locate_first_regex(rquote, "u")[,1]), "r|R")
# [1] 5
## count all R or r
stri_count_regex(rquote, "r|R")
# [1] 6
```

Comment: No worries.  This was fun, I like these problems

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just saw `before the first u`.  In that case, we can get the position of the first 'u' from either `which` or `match`.
Then use `grepl` in the 'chars' up to the position (ind) to find the logical index of 'R'  with `ignore.case=TRUE` and use `sum` using the `strsplit` output from the OP's code.

```
ind <- which(chars=='u')[1]
```

Or

```
ind <-  match('u', chars)  
sum(grepl('r', chars[seq(ind)], ignore.case=TRUE))
#[1] 5
```

Or we can use two `gsub`s on the original string ('rquote').  First one removes the characters starting with `u` until the end of the string (`u.$`) and the second matches all characters except R, r (`[^Rr]`) and replace it with `''`.  We can use `nchar` to get count of the characters remaining.

```
nchar(gsub('[^Rr]', '', sub('u.*$', '', rquote)))
#[1] 5
```

---

Or if we want to count the 'r' in the entire string, `gregexpr` to get the position of matching characters from the original string ('rquote') and get the `length`

```
length(gregexpr('[rR]', rquote)[[1]])
#[1] 6
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj were you using chars or rquote inside the grepl statement?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't know why you get that.  Perhaps somebody else can test the code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
> length(str_extract_all(rquote, '[Rr]')[[1]])
[1] 6
```

To get the count of all `r`'s before the first `u`

```
> length(str_extract_all(rquote, perl('u.*(*SKIP)(*F)|[Rr]'))[[1]])
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of R's before the first u, you need to make an intermediate step. (You probably don't need to.  I'm sure akrun knows some incredibly cool regular expression to get the job done, but it won't be as easy to understand as this).

```
rquote <- "R's internals are irrefutably intriguing"
before_u <- gsub("u[[:print:]]+$", "", rquote)
length(stringr::str_extract_all(before_u, "(R|r)")[[1]])
```